# How to make the command tree on linux show only folders?

Tags: linux, directory, tree

I had a project that i was trying to understand the architecture and see the folder arrangement, so needed see just folders, and the command `tree`.

This command helps to show the tree of the packages and files, and i just need to see the folders.

> How i see just the folders in tree, to i can understand the architecture?

Answer (score 2):

For solve this problem a added `-d` of "**D**irectory" on the command `tree`, and became:

```
tree -d
```

The result is that, I was able to see and understand all the packages of a selected area from [Domain Driven Design Github Repository](https://github.com/skatesham/dddsample-core) (DDD).

[image: Domain Driven Design internal packages]